# extracting data from openweather api

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, openweathermap

I am trying to extract country weather data from the openweather api and add it to a data frame to be able to create a csv file, but I am running into some problems. I imported the data and when I print it, I am able to see the requested data(humidity, temperature, wind speed etc.) in formatted form. I started to run into problems when I create my dataframe.

```
import requests 
import pandas as pd 
import json
from datetime import datetime

API_key = ''

countries = ['Jamaica', 'Haiti', 'Montserrat', 'Barbados', 'Cuba', 'Dominican Republic', 'Saint Lucia', 'Antigua and Barbuda', 'Belize', 'Aruba']

for country_names in countries:
    
    url = f'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={country_names}&APPID={API_key}&units=imperial'
    
    r = requests.get(url)
    
    #if (r.status_code == 200):
        
    data = r.json()
        
    formatted_json = json.dumps(data, sort_keys = True, indent = 4)
        
    
    caribbean_countries = []
    maxtemp = []
    mintemp = []
    humidity = []
    weather = []
    windspeed = []
    
    caribbean_countries.append(data['name'])
    #name = data['name']
    maxtemp.append(data['main']['temp_max'])
    mintemp.append(data['main']['temp_min'])
    humidity.append(data['main']['humidity'])
    weather.append(data['weather'][0]['description'])
    windspeed.append(data['wind']['speed'])
        

countries_weather_df = pd.DataFrame()
countries_weather_df['Names'] = caribbean_countries
countries_weather_df['Max_Temp'] = maxtemp
countries_weather_df['Min_Temp'] = mintemp
countries_weather_df['Humidity'] = humidity
countries_weather_df['Weather'] = weather
countries_weather_df['WindSpeed'] = windspeed

countries_weather_df
```

The result only shows one country. How do I show all the requested countries and put it into a dataframe?

How can I show all the countries in the dataframe?

Comment: You're resetting the `caribbean_countries` (and all the other lists) every time you go through the loop. You should move that code (`caribbean_countries = []` etc.) before the loop

Comment: Each iteration you create NEW data frame and overwrite it, you don't store it or append to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move `caribbean_countries` before the for loop or else it'll overwrite each iteration. You also need to do this for your other values or they'll be overwritten too.

```
import requests 
import pandas as pd 
import json
from datetime import datetime

API_key = ''

countries = ['Jamaica', 'Haiti', 'Montserrat', 'Barbados', 'Cuba', 'Dominican Republic', 'Saint Lucia', 'Antigua and Barbuda', 'Belize', 'Aruba']

caribbean_countries = []
maxtemp = []
mintemp = []
humidity = []
weather = []
windspeed = []

for country_names in countries:
    
    url = f'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={country_names}&APPID={API_key}&units=imperial'
    
    r = requests.get(url)
    
    #if (r.status_code == 200):
        
    data = r.json()
        
    formatted_json = json.dumps(data, sort_keys = True, indent = 4)

    caribbean_countries.append(data['name'])
    #name = data['name']
    maxtemp.append(data['main']['temp_max'])
    mintemp.append(data['main']['temp_min'])
    humidity.append(data['main']['humidity'])
    weather.append(data['weather'][0]['description'])
    windspeed.append(data['wind']['speed'])
        

countries_weather_df = pd.DataFrame()
countries_weather_df['Names'] = caribbean_countries
countries_weather_df['Max_Temp'] = maxtemp
countries_weather_df['Min_Temp'] = mintemp
countries_weather_df['Humidity'] = humidity
countries_weather_df['Weather'] = weather
countries_weather_df['WindSpeed'] = windspeed

countries_weather_df
```